# how to check which replica set is read in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I setup a mongodb replica set, and i have tested the insert operation, the secondary server can sync with the primary. Now, I want to check where i do the read operation, which server is handling the request. How can I check it? in mongodb log? or somewhere else.

Btw: My driver is Mongoid. 
many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `mongostat --discover`. This will show you the statistics for all members in the replica set. When a read is performed you can see which member is servicing the request.

Note that reads will only go to the non-primary member if your queries use `slaveOk`